# Why are public and private accessors considered good practice?

Tags: c#, object-oriented

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When are Getters and Setters Justified](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/when-are-getters-and-setters-justified)

Why exactly is having public and private accessors like these:

```
private string foo;

public string Foo
{
    get
    {
        return foo;
    }
    set
    {
        foo = value;
    }
}
```

considered better than just having public ones like this:

```
public string Foo;
```

The end result seems to be the same.

Comment: In which language? In Python for instance it isn't.

Comment: Im using c#. Edited to clarify

Comment: Also see [Getters and Setters in functional languages](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/96429/getters-and-setters-in-functional-languages) for the functional side of things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Properties do not have the same semantics as public variables:

- Reflection works differently on variables vs. properties, so if you rely on reflection, it's easier to always use properties.
- You can't databind against a variable.
- Changing a variable to a property is a [breaking change,](https://web.archive.org/web/20160229201701/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/04/11/572694.aspx) if you decide you want to add validation or other logic later.

2. [Automatic properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) make it easier to use public properties exclusively.

Comment: +1 "Changing a variable to a property is a breaking change"

Answer (score 1):

So you can protect the internal state of your classes.

You can set the property to have validation happen during set (some argue this should be done with a method)

You can hide variables that the user of the class should never see nor modify.

I don't care about your internal counter, or whatever other variables you need.  And modifying certain variables in a class will completely break it.

Comment: The OP is referring to the common case of exposing a private field via a public property, without validation logic. He wonders, why not just make the field public? The property is not hiding anything, and no internal state is being protected.

Comment: Ah, I  misunderstood.  However, they ARE still different as you outlined in your reply.  I've +1'd your response.

Answer (score 0):

In this example it's proabably not any advantage, but when systems get large and complex it can really come in useful to restrict a classes "access points".

Comment: For example you may have 2 private variables x , y but a single "access point" get getCoordinate

Comment: Then you need a Coordinate class ;)

Answer (score -1):

One reason might be that you want to perform some validation or additional operations in the setter.

(Sorry mis-read this first, have edited my answer)