# What is the benefit of using getters and setters on properties in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When are Getters and Setters Justified](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/when-are-getters-and-setters-justified)

Why do we use get and set method in C#? And why do we use public and private method property?

For example:

```
public class Date
{
    private int month = 7;  
    public int Month
    {
        get
        {
            return month;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value > 0) && (value < 13))
            {
                month = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is covered in depth here: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/when-are-getters-and-setters-justified, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120828/are-get-set-methods-a-violation-of-encapsulation, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38423/is-it-a-good-programming-practice-to-not-use-getters-and-setters-in-trivial-part and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144347/when-or-why-should-one-use-getters-setters-for-class-properties-instead-of-simpl among many others

Comment: Those are *two* questions, not one.

Answer (score 9):

`Private set modifier` is used to control the access to object's property value.

`Public set modifier` is **directly accessing** the object's property value.

When you have a closed Domain, as a rule of open/close principle, private set modifiers used to restrict direct access to modify the properties of the object.

Private setters were not available before .NET 2.0 Framework. This has meant that people have written separate SetXXX methods if they wanted a public getter but a more limited setter.

```
public class MyTest
{
    string someProperty;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return someProperty;
        }

        private set
        {
            someProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The basic rules are that you can't specify an access modifier for both the getter and the setter, and you have to use the "extra" modifier to make access more restrictive than the rest of the property.

Your question example comes from MSDN article [Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
Look at that again and it will clear up the things.

Comment: @imonbayazid, please have a look - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/187724